# EnumerableExtensions.Join inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: join, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-2.1

am getting a Enumerable Extensions join is inaccessible due to its protection level error. I am using EF Core for database connections. How to perform joins using LINQ ??

```
var seatBookings =(
from sb in Context.SeatBookings
join bd in Context.BookingDetails on sb.BookingId 
equals bd.Id
where bd.ShowId == showId
select sb
).ToList();


public partial class SeatBookings
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public int? BookingId { get; set; }
public int SeatNumber { get; set; }

public BookingDetails Booking { get; set; }
}



public partial class BookingDetails
{
public BookingDetails()
{
SeatBookings = new HashSet<SeatBookings>();
}

public int Id { get; set; }
public int ShowId { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
public int TheaterId { get; set; }
public int BookedSeatsCount { get; set; }

public ShowDetails Show { get; set; }
public ICollection<SeatBookings> SeatBookings { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Add `using System.Linq;`?

Comment: Unrelated, but in EF queries we usually use navigation properties instead of manual joins, e.g. `var seatBookings = Context.SeatBookings.Where(sb => sb.Booking.ShowId == showId).ToList();`

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks! It was a stupid mistake , should have checked my code before posting question.

Comment: Not a problem, it happens :)

Comment: @IvanStoev By the way, can you please suggest any good resources where i can study about using navigation properties with some examples

Comment: It's quite simple when you realize that you can use them inside the queries like if they were objects/collections, and then EF would convert them to joins. Here is one good post that I sometimes link to  - [Don’t use Linq’s Join. Navigate!](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/)

Comment: Thanks a Tonn!  I couldn't find any good posts/blog about the navigational properties in google search. I am new to this , helps a lot. @IvanStoev